# Excel fractions miscalculated

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula, fractions

I'm trying to calculate screen ratios in Excel. I have a column with x and y, an example of what I'd expect from the calculated ratio column is:

```
 x    | y    | ratio
 1920 | 1080 | 16/9
```

but by using the formula =x/y and formatting the ratio column as a fraction I get:

```
 x    | y    | ratio
 1920 | 1080 | 17/9
```

I assume this is something to do with rounding error, but is there any way around this, in order to show accurate screen resolution ratios?

Comment: For improper fractions you can use `??/??` in the custom formatting slot.

Comment: pnuts yes, it is 1 7/9, hadn't figured that out, I think because I was expecting 16/9 and it's only one out I misread it. Joe, thanks! That's exactly what I need :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@pnuts is right.  You can change the output by using a custom format.  Right click on the cell and choose format.  Then use the following custom numbering.

[image]