# Output fraction instead of decimal in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, number-formatting

I am trying to display the solution to an equation in VBA as an unreduced fraction, but VBA automatically evaluates the equation to a decimal. Does anybody know how to keep it as an original fraction?

I've tried converting the integers to strings and then dividing them, but excel still automatically converts everything to a decimal.

```
Dim workingmegawattsint As Integer
workingmegawattsint = workingturbinesint * turbineCapacity
Dim totalmegawattsint As Integer
totalmegawattsint = totalturbinesint * turbineCapacity
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value = workingmegawattsint / totalmegawattsint
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19007031/excel-fractions-miscalculated if you just want to change the custom number format

Comment: VBA does not / will not store numeric values as fractions. Depending on the data type, the values are stored as binary values with a storage requirement of 1 to 14 bytes.  The results can be displayed as a fraction, or as a decimal, or as an integer (or as something else), depending on how your format the result.  If you want to use a specific denominator, you need to custom format your result, or the worksheet cell accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

Just enter it like a string:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value = workingmegawattsint & "/" & totalmegawattsint
```

May want to tweak with `TEXT()` depending on how long/what the numbers are.